# Bearer {token) with NSMutableRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest

I need to call the service with pass the access token in the header.

But i thing the token is not going on the header. I am not getting the responce. what am i doing wrong?

**Code**

```
 +(void)getUserwithToken:(NSString *)token{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://exapmle.com/api/users"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",str1);
    }];
}
```

**OutPut :connectionError : (null)
       , str1 : {}**

Comment: You need to do some debugging: If you are getting an error `NSLog(@"connectionError: %@", connectionError)` and add the result to the question. Also take a look at the network request with Charles Proxy.

Comment: I have updated the question. i just want to know if i am doing wrong any. because if i pass header or not responce is same. So may be service is not getting the header

Comment: Is the value in the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with the request:

1. You are not checking for and handling error conditions.
2. You are issuing a POST request but there is not body (data), generally such requests are issued as GET requests.